# Get a custom Qt QGraphicsView to display in a form made with Qt Designer

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer, qgraphicsview

I put together a custom QGraphicsView that I can get to show in a main window in Python, but am struggling to get it integrated into a form I made with Qt Designer.  How would I add this into a form?

Also, I've added a mousepress event as well.  How would that also be integrated into app using a form made with Qt Designer?  I've build an entire app using Qt Designer and everything else work, I just need to be able to add this piece together with the rest of it.

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QAction, QSlider
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QListWidget, QTabWidget, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QSpinBox, QWidget, QDialog, QVBoxLayout
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage, QMatrix, QPainter, QColor, QMouseEvent, QCursor
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, QObject, SIGNAL

import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

class Display_Pixels(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        #super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.img = cv2.imread('roi.jpg')

    def initUI(self):      
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 650, 650)
        #self.setWindowTitle('By Pixel')
        #self.setMouseTracking(True)
        #self.show()
        res = 40 
        self.grid = np.array([ [-1] * res  for n in range(res)]) # list comprehension
        #print(self.grid.shape)


    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self.viewport())
        self.drawRectangles(qp)
        qp.end()


    def drawRectangles(self, qp, w = 16):
        print("Drawing")
        mode = 0
        x,y = 0,0 # starting position
        lr = 20
        hr = 35
        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(col)
        #print(self.img.shape)

        for g_row, img_row in zip(self.grid, self.img):
            #print(img_row.shape)
            for g_col, img_col in zip(g_row, img_row):
                r, g, b = (img_col[0], img_col[1], img_col[2])
                #print(r,g,b)

                if g_col == 1:
                    if mode == 0:
                        r = int(math.log(r+1)*lr)
                        g = int(math.log(g+1)*hr)
                        b = int(math.log(b+1)*lr)
                    elif mode == 1:
                        if r+50 <= 220: r = r+50
                        if g+80 <= 255: g = g+80
                        if b+50 <= 220: b = b+50
                    else:
                        if r+70 <= 220: r = r+70
                        if g+140 <= 255: g = g+140
                        if b+70 <= 220: b = b+70

                    qp.setBrush(QColor(r, g, b))
                    qp.drawRect(x, y, w, w)
                else:
                    qp.setBrush(QColor(r, g, b))
                    qp.drawRect(x, y, w, w)

                #qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
                #qp.drawRect(x, y, w, w)
                x = x + w  # move right
            y = y + w # move down
            x = 0 # rest to left edge


    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        w = 16.0

        #print("MOUSE:")
        #print('(', int(QMouseEvent.x()/w), ', ', int(QMouseEvent.y()/w), ')')
        #print (QMouseEvent.pos())
        x = float(QMouseEvent.x())
        y = float(QMouseEvent.y())
        self.grid[int(y/w)][int(x/w)] = -1 * self.grid[int(y/w)][int(x/w)]

        #print(img[int(y/w), int(x/w), :])

        self.repaint()
        #self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication.instance()
    if app is None: 
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    px = Display_Pixels()
    px.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what your saying is that you successfully added this code to a main window, but you instead want to be able to add this into a widget you made in designer and not strictly a main window.

If that is the case what you will want to do is format your widget how you want in Qt Designer add a place holder such as a frame, layout, maybe a group, etc where you want to insert your Display_Pixels QGraphicsView object.

After that wont be directly adding it to the frame, but instead whatever layout that frame is using. so if you have a gridlayout in your frame it would be something like:

```
    self.Disp_pixel = Display_Pixels()
    widget_name.gridlayout.addWidget(self.Disp_pixel)
```

It is hard to tell you where this code would be implemented in your code but hypothetically lets say you ran pyuic5 and got the python output. You could add it in that output python file. I would recommend having something like a viewer class that inherits the generated output class and do the add widget in there. Also frame would be the name of the frame you created for the graphics view and not literally frame.

Also I'm not sure if you can do a show on just any type of widget I'm pretty sure the widget has to be displayable such as a main window widget or a dialog widget. That being said widgets can be placed in other widgets.

Here is an example I have for you its a little rough, but I think it will help:

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsView, QApplication

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '.\testUI.ui' and .\testMainWin.ui
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))


class FormView(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FormView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.disp_pixels = Display_Pixels()
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.disp_pixels)


class MainView(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Display_Pixels(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        #super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.img = cv2.imread('resources/images/pic3.jpg')

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 650, 650)
        #self.setWindowTitle('By Pixel')
        #self.setMouseTracking(True)
        #self.show()
        res = 40
        self.grid = np.array([ [-1] * res  for n in range(res)]) # list comprehension
        #print(self.grid.shape)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self.viewport())
        self.drawRectangles(qp)
        qp.end()


    def drawRectangles(self, qp, w = 16):
        print("Drawing")
        mode = 0
        x,y = 0,0 # starting position
        lr = 20
        hr = 35
        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(col)
        #print(self.img.shape)

        for g_row, img_row in zip(self.grid, self.img):
            #print(img_row.shape)
            for g_col, img_col in zip(g_row, img_row):
                r, g, b = (img_col[0], img_col[1], img_col[2])
                #print(r,g,b)

                if g_col == 1:
                    if mode == 0:
                        r = int(math.log(r+1)*lr)
                        g = int(math.log(g+1)*hr)
                        b = int(math.log(b+1)*lr)
                    elif mode == 1:
                        if r+50 <= 220: r = r+50
                        if g+80 <= 255: g = g+80
                        if b+50 <= 220: b = b+50
                    else:
                        if r+70 <= 220: r = r+70
                        if g+140 <= 255: g = g+140
                        if b+70 <= 220: b = b+70

                    qp.setBrush(QColor(r, g, b))
                    qp.drawRect(x, y, w, w)
                else:
                    qp.setBrush(QColor(r, g, b))
                    qp.drawRect(x, y, w, w)

                #qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
                #qp.drawRect(x, y, w, w)
                x = x + w  # move right
            y = y + w # move down
            x = 0 # rest to left edge


    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        w = 16.0

        #print("MOUSE:")
        #print('(', int(QMouseEvent.x()/w), ', ', int(QMouseEvent.y()/w), ')')
        #print (QMouseEvent.pos())
        x = float(QMouseEvent.x())
        y = float(QMouseEvent.y())
        self.grid[int(y/w)][int(x/w)] = -1 * self.grid[int(y/w)][int(x/w)]

        #print(img[int(y/w), int(x/w), :])

        self.repaint()
        #self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainView()
    form = FormView()
    main_window.gridLayout.addWidget(form)
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I added the following lines of code that seemed to do the trick:

        self.edit_layout = self.window.findChild(QHBoxLayout, 'Editor_Layout')
        self.view = Display_Pixels()
        self.view.installEventFilter(self)
        self.edit_layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.view.show()

Comment: This is unrelated, but my coding skills are clearly not the best.  I'm still at a loss as to why it's better to have seperate classes for the main window and the form.  Also, what's the point of the child classes?

Comment: It really depends on you. I like to keep things separated out like that. I'm using a design pattern close to model, view, controller so it works for me. You don't have to do it that way though. the code will pretty much be the same, except the 2 lines of code in FormView where I initialize the Display_Pixels and then add it to the gridlayout, that would be moved to the Ui_Form class.

also Ui_Form is generated off of a ui file I created and then converted to python using pyuic5 so you would want to make your own more than likely. That is up to you though.

Comment: Ahh MVC, i forgot about this!  Its been a long time since i did coding classes at uni.  Thanks so much for your help!